# VBA Excel Call and Run breaking backtracking

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making a workbook with a whole lot of different subs, and in an effort to avoid a user accidentally activating a sub that erases the code of a sheet for example, I've tried making all the subs private instead.

My subs can now only be activated by clicking buttons on the worksheet, and it all works as intended. Untill a sub of mine tries to call a private sub in another module of course.

To get around this I used `Application.Run` rather than `Call`, which worked and also allows me to call in a variable "NextSub" from the previous sub, which gives me some flexibility that I need, and apparently cant get with the `Call`.

Eg.

```
Sub FirstSub()
*Something going on
Application.Run "SecondSub", SomeVariableSub
End sub

Sub SecondSub(Nextsub as String)
If something Then
   *Do something
   Application.Run NextSub
Else
   Application.Run NextSub
```

I thought that the `Application.Run` had solved all my problems, but I used to have a line that called an errorhandler, which in turn called a sub. It seems that the program can no longer backtrack to the sub that contained the errorhandler as it could when I used `Call`.

Does `Applciation.Run` break this functionality? If yes, can I then use `Call` with a variable NextSub as I am doing it now? And if I can't use the `Call` that way, then is all this fixed by adding a `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` in the affected subs?

I know that the whole thing about calling Private Subs across modules is probably pretty bad practice, but I was compltely new to this when I started out, and the project is too extensive to fix that without rewriting all of the code.

Comment: Can you try `Call Module1.SubName`?

Comment: What do you mean by `a user accidentally activating a sub`? You should (almost) never use `Application.Run`.

Comment: @Stenci If they enter Macros and activate one of the subs from there, it might turn out to be catastrophic

Comment: @Ian I've tried that as well, but it still acts up when using the call fuction. It seems the call wants a specific path and does not accept a concatenated name nor a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making all subs private, either put Option Private Module on top of each module, or add a dummy argument to each routine:

```html
Sub SomeHiddenRoutine(bDummy As Boolean = False)
    'Routine can be called as usual using:
    SomeHiddenRoutine
End Sub
```

Comment: Alright, that would hide them, and that's fantastic, but then I'm back to using `Call`, and I have yet to figure out how to pass a variable sub name with the call funtion. It seems as if `Call` needs the exact name of a function while `Application.Run` can accept a string of text

Comment: Hmm, OK I missed that piece, sorry. Indeed, Application.run causes the called sub to ignore any pre-existing error handlers so you will have to make sure the called routines have their own error handler.

Comment: Fair enough, the error handler I need is just two lines anyway as I need it to just call a sub and then be on its merry way. Shame that it goes and ignores it though

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you are trying to call a function specified by a string.

The correct way is to use something like this, which allows you to call all the private subs (as long as it is in the same module as the private functions):

```
Sub CallFunction(FuncName As String)
  Select Case FuncName
    Case "Func1": Func1
    Case "Func2": Func2
    Case "Func3": Func3
  End Select
End Sub
```